# Is there a way to add a property to a GTK widget/object to store additional information about it

Tags: widget, gtk3

I have many GTK widgets/GObjects in my project.  I would like to be able to attach some information to each object as it is created and then when the object is passed to some generic library routine, be able to retrieve this widget/GObject specific information for processing purposes

I have looked into the GObject manual and think I can by using some of these routines.  But every time I check something out, I have to trace multiple definitions which require further research.  I am lost.  I was looking for some simple example that might put it all in perspective.

I would like to be able to enter something like (Code example in FreeBasic)

```basic
dim as GtkWidget Ptr widget = gtk_button_new("Press Me")
```

then add a line something like this

```basic
add_property(widget,"username","Andrew Loy",-1)
```

Then in some generic library error reporting routine where widget is stored in some generic heap.

```basic
Sub ReportError(widget as GtkWidget Ptr)
dim as Zstring ptr     NameOfUser

    get_property(widget,"username",@NameOfUser,-1)
    print *NameOfUser
```

I want the widget/GObject to carry around more information than is provided by standard GTK.  A simple pointer would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`g_object_set_data()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/method.Object.set_data.html), which allows you to associate any pointer with a GObject, using a string key.